# how to make picturebox.image = one picture in an array?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I think i need to store the string s and bitmap bmp in an array then i think  i have to pick one image in the bmp array to show in the picture box but im not sure how.

```
  public partial class capstoneProjectForm : Form
{
    string imageName;
    //string[] a;
    Bitmap[] bit;
    string[] folder;
    int numOfPics;
    int num = 0;
    public capstoneProjectForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;


      //  a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
        string resFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "Resources");


        foreach (string s in Directory.EnumerateFiles(resFolder, "*.jpg"))
        {

           using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(s))
            {


            }
           if (s.Equals(imageName))
                {
                    pictureBox.Image = ;
                }



        }
```

Comment: Correct. there is no name in a bitmap.. only a bitmap

Comment: well can i get the index of an image in the folder?

Comment: You are opening the file, and doing nothing with it - there is no index, there is no nothing, you have momentarily a picture, but nothing more. If you want to store it in a dictionary, or, list or structure/class then you can store filename + picture, or something, but right now, your code works as expected

Comment: i need to be able to compare the image name to a selected item in a list box then the picture box displays the image based on listbox selected

Comment: well firstly, the image has no name. the file does. so, you have the filename... if you need to do something with it - show your code trying, cos right now, you open it as a bitmap, and do absolutely nothing with it.. other than prove you can open it.